# HighChart on Android dynamically update

Tags: java, javascript, android, highcharts

I try to use HighCharts in my android application, but I can't find samples for Android. I added chart from official examples to my application, but I can't understand, how dynamically update data in control.

Comment: Maybe check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14844908/android-ios-apps-with-highcharts-running-in-webview

Comment: user2842993 can u plz proide the url i m also stuck in this thing or share the comple code for Highchart android

Comment: hello can you suggest how to start highchart in android? I am new with js using in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't really used HighCharts , but I believe you are using a webview in android, and calling some javascript function that takes in some parameters and display it as charts.

If this is the flow, then you need to make a javascript function through which you will take some data and display it in the charts. Then to call that function, you have to call:

```
WebView.loadUrl("javascript:plotLine('[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]')");
```

Hope that helps